# Place Button to the Bottom Right of a List

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-float

Please see attached code snippet. I have an 'item' component, where I'm going to dynamically retrieve the Title and some bullet descriptions.

Each Item is going to have an 'Add Item' button, which I'd like to be aligned to the bottom right of the list - **not underneath**.

How can I do this whilst ensuring that the list text drops onto a new line where appropriate?

I want to avoid putting the span within the list. Is there a Bootstrap way of doing this and if not is there an alternative way?

Thank you,

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  <body>
    <div class="container bg-info">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h1>Item Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <span type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add Item</span>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Description 1, Description 1, Description 1, Description 1</li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Description 2
            </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Description 3, Description 3, Description 3, Description 3</li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Description 4, Description 4, Description 4, Des 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Can you move your button to the end, instead of before the list?

Comment: Hi @Armin. If I do that, I get the button *underneath* the list.

Comment: But I think it would be easier to style it to appear where you want it. Actually, when you say underneath, you mean underneath the text, or underneath the box?

Comment: If I understand correct... he wants the text to wrap around the button while button is placed on the bottom-right on the list.

Comment: @NawedKhan I think so. First time I misunderstood.

Comment: @AntonRand I think it would be challenging to do it if the button is outside of the list. You can always reduce the width of the last <li> element and place button at the bottom right, but it's not the best practice. It's the easiest workaround I can think of atm.

Comment: @NawedKhan is correct - sorry for the explanation!

OK, would rather avoid that but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: What would have really helped here is a simple mock-up of what your output currently looks like, and how you *want* it to look.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use position

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

**EDIT**
try adding width to your ul

```
.list-unstyled {
    width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it but the problem I have is the Absolute Positioning will obscure some of the text in my last list element. Please see this illustration: http://imgur.com/a/k1slf

Answer (score -1):

```
<body>
    <div class="container bg-info">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <h1>Item Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8">        
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Description 1, Description 1, Description 1, Description 1</li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Description 2
            </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
            Description 3, Description 3, Description 3, Description 3</li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            Description 4, Description 4, Description 4, Des 4
               <span type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Add Item</span>
          </li>             
        </ul>      
      </div>     
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: "I want to avoid putting the span within the list."